# Is allowing "data:" in CSP Trusted Sites a security concern?

Tags: lightning-web-components, base64, csp

We have a requirement to display a pdf embedded in a LWC. The pdf is base64 encoded and we would prefer not to store it as File. It is many places suggested to add "data:" as a an allowed scheme in CSP trusted sites and load the pdf in an iframe.

Adding "data:" as an allowed seems very broad. Is this a security concern / are we opening for any attacks?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Data URI scheme has been known to be exploitable, but the risk level depends on the environment. If there is a way for a malicious actor to trick the system into delivering a malicious payload, then that presents a possible security risk. It's probably safe to use in most orgs, although I'd suggest using a Static Resource instead.